# Where does the web.config/app.config file live for SharePoint timer services?

Tags: sharepoint

Not sure if this would be an app.config or a web.config.

I was thinking it would be in the directory that the Central Administration website lives in but it doesn't look like that's it.  Where can I find this?

Comment: WOW!!  Abe Miessler...rep score:6,666....spooky.

Comment: I know... Thank god someone upvoted me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**SharePoint 2007:** `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE.config`

**SharePoint 2010:** `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE.config`

**SharePoint 2013:** `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE.config`

**SharePoint 2016:** `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\16\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE.config`

**In a word:** `[12/14/15/16 hive]\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE.config`

Comment: Your are right. But the path you have mentioned is not working for me. Instead of 14 it will be in 15 .

Comment: I posted this 7 years ago, so a new version of SharePoint must have been released since then. Feel free to edit this post and add the information about the "15" path. @VijayalakshmiS